# 404 error when calling server endpoint, restarted server and checked spelling

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm getting the below error and have been stumped for about two hours trying to figure out what I'm missing. I've reset my local server several times, and can call other similarly defined endpoints.

This is the error.

```
ProjectList.jsx:130 
 POST http://localhost:3000/update-project-numbers 404 (Not Found)
react_devtools_backend.js:2655 Error updating project numbers: 
Response {type: 'basic', url: 'http://localhost:3000/update-project-numbers', redirected: false, status: 404, ok: false, …}
```

I checked the server.js file, and this is how it's structured

```
app.post('/update-project-numbers', (req, res) => {
    const projectUpdates = req.body;
    const values = projectUpdates.map((update) => [update.project_number, update.project_id]);
    const query = 'UPDATE projects SET project_number = $1 WHERE project_id = $2';
    client.query(query, values, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            res.status(500).send('Error updating projects');
        } else {
            res.send('Projects updated successfully');
        }
    });
});
```

This is how I call it from elsewhere in my code.

```
            const response = await fetch('/update-project-numbers', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(updatedProjectsPayload)
            });

            if (response.status === 201) {
                console.log('Project numbers updated successfully');
            } else {
                console.error('Error updating project numbers:', response);
            }
```

I tried using Postman and get "Error updating projects" "500 Internal Server Error"

I haven't been able to find anything else useful to debug the issue. I'm just trying to restart the program and server repeatedly expecting something to change, is there anything else I can try?

Comment: You seem to be making a request to the same server that serves the frontend. Perhaps you want to try `fetch("http://localhost:<server-port>/update-project-numbers", ...)`

Comment: Thank you so much. I know coding for 12 hours in one day was a bad idea. Never would have caught that.